# SQL left join with n conditions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, multiple-conditions

Hi i got this database with cars and every car has options

I got a cars table and a options table. Link one to many, a car has n options a option has exactly one car.

I use the database to filter for cars with specific options (combination of options).

I am working with SQLite.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars WHERE cars.id IN (SELECT cars.id 
                    FROM cars
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option1 ON cars.id = option1.car_id 
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option2 ON cars.id = option2.car_id 
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option3 ON cars.id = option3.car_id 
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option4 ON cars.id = option4.car_id 
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option5 ON cars.id = option5.car_id 
                    LEFT JOIN options AS option6 ON cars.id = option6.car_id 
                    WHERE cars.vin LIKE '%EA40%'
                        AND option1.options_number = 415
                        AND option2.options_number = 362
                        AND option3.options_number = 502
                        AND option4.options_description like "Bordcomputer"
                        AND option5.options_number = 494
                        AND option6.options_number = 530
                        ) ;
```

This is just a hobby project and i am not a professional, this solution while it is working looks and feels very wrong to me with all those joins.

I hope someone can give me a hint in a more streamlined shorter version.

My goal would be to make n options searchable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to convert left joins to `exists`. That way you can easily change the where clause (if 4 options were specified then 4 exists clauses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` is superfluous. There must be no duplicate rows in a car table. One row per car. No duplicates. Whenever you use `DISTINCT` ask yourself what forces you to use it. `DISTINCT` is a keyword that you should need very rarely. (Often `DISTINCT` is an indicator even for a poorly written query.)

You don't need outer joins. If you only want cars that have the options, it must be inner joins. With outer joins you'd get all cars, because the outer join tells the DBMS: "give me all cars regardless whether you find a match in the option table or not". Your "outer" joins however are obfuscated inner joins (this is why the query works for you). In a result row that had no match in the outer joined table, the outer joined table's columns are all null. A `WHERE o1.options_number = 415` dismisses such rows, so you turn the outer join into an inner join. Don't do that. Only outer join when you want to outer join. And if you outer join a table, put the conditions for the join into the `ON` clause.

Moreover `WHERE options_description like "Bordcomputer"` is invalid SQL unless you have a column called "Bordcomputer". String literals have single quotes: 'Bordcomputer'. And then, why `LIKE`? What is this supposed to do? `LIKE` is for pattern matching, e.g. `WHERE options_description LIKE 'B_rdcom%'`. You want equality, so use `=`, not `LIKE`.

At last, why the subquery? Why select all car IDs from the car table in order to select the car rows from the car table again?

Your query corrected:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN options AS o1 ON o1.car_id = c.id AND o1.options_number = 415
INNER JOIN options AS o2 ON o2.car_id = c.id AND o2.options_number = 362
INNER JOIN options AS o3 ON o3.car_id = c.id AND o3.options_number = 502
INNER JOIN options AS o4 ON o4.car_id = c.id AND o4.options_description = 'Bordcomputer'
INNER JOIN options AS o5 ON o5.car_id = c.id AND o5.options_number = 494
INNER JOIN options AS o6 ON o6.car_id = c.id AND o6.options_number = 530
WHERE c.vin LIKE '%EA40%';
```

But you are right: It doesn't look good with all the joins. Why is that? Because we select data `FROM` tables, and you only want data *from* the car table, and we tell the DBMS which rows we want in the `WHERE` clause. In order to look up other tables, we use `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE vin LIKE '%EA40%'
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_number = 415)
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_number = 362)
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_number = 502)
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_description = 'Bordcomputer')
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_number = 494)
AND id IN (SELECT car_id FROM options WHERE options_number = 530);
```

At last you have the option to aggregate the options per car and only get the car IDs that have all the options. E.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE vin LIKE '%EA40%'
AND id IN 
(
  SELECT car_id
  FROM options
  GROUP BY car_id
  HAVING SUM(options_number = 415) > 0
     AND SUM(options_number = 362) > 0
     AND SUM(options_number = 502) > 0
     AND SUM(options_description = 'Bordcomputer') > 0
     AND SUM(options_number = 494) > 0
     AND SUM(options_number = 530) > 0
);
```

(This works, because in SQLite true = 1, false = 0, so if we add up the matches, we get 0 when there is no match. In other DBMS you'd need `SUM(CASE WHEN options_number = 415 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` or `COUNT(CASE WHEN options_number = 415 THEN 1 END)`. The SQL standard offers the most readable option in my opinion, but only few DBMS support it yet: `COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE options_number = 415)`.)

So if the option_number is unique, what I suppose it is, then the latter subquery becomes a mere

```
(
  SELECT car_id
  FROM options
  GROUP BY car_id
  HAVING SUM(options_number IN (362, 415, 494, 502, 530)) = 5
     AND SUM(options_description = 'Bordcomputer') > 0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an existence check in other table for all those options:

```
SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE vin LIKE '%EA40%'
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_number = 415)
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_number = 362)
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_number = 502)
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_number = 494)
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_number = 530)
 and exists (select * from options where options.car_id = cars.id and options.options_description like "Bordcomputer");
```

PS: With a backend like postgreSQL this could be easier, keeping options in an array.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT distinct cars.* 
FROM cars 
inner JOIN options ON cars.id = options.car_id
WHERE cars.vin LIKE '%EA40%'
AND options.options_number in ( 415, 362, 502, 494, 530)
AND options.options_description like "Bordcomputer"
;
```

**Attempt 2**

This could be implemented with only 2 joins - one for the options_numbers and one for the options_descriptions.

It might be possible to reduce it to only a single join if the options_number for 'Bordcomputer' (or any other filter on options_descriptions) could be determined in a previous step/CTE

```
select cars.*
from cars
inner join options opt1 on cars.id = opt1.car_id and opt1.options_number in (362, 415, 494, 502, 530)
inner join options opt2 on cars.id = opt2.car_id and opt2. options_description in ('Bordcomputer')
WHERE cars.vin LIKE '%EA40%'
group by cars.id, cars.vin
having listagg(distinct opt1.options_number, '|') within group (order by opt1.options_number) = '362|415|494|502|530'
and listagg(distinct opt2.options_description, '|') within group (order by opt2.options_description) = 'Bordcomputer'
;
```

Comment: OP wants to have all those conditions. This would return those with only 415 and 'bordcomputer' too for example. Although he used left join, he implies an inner join through the use of where filters.

Comment: This query is incorrect, It requires at least one option of the five IDs to be the 'Bordcomputer'.  This is not part of the task. And yes, Cetin Bazos is right, it seems you have misunderstood the task, as your query gets cars that have at least one match, while the OP wants the cars that have all matches.